# Error when deploying Lektor site to Github Pages using Travis CI

Tags: travis-ci, github-pages, lektor

I've got a Lektor site that I'm trying to deploy automatically in response to pull requests and commits, using the [Travis CI trigger approach from the Lektor docs](https://www.getlektor.com/docs/deployment/travisci/).

The Lektor configuration works fine from the command line.

The Travis build starts, and appears to build the site without problem - but when it gets to deployment, the log says the following:

```
Installing deploy dependencies
!!! Script support is experimental !!!

Preparing deploy
Cleaning up git repository with `git stash --all`. If you need build artifacts for deployment, set `deploy.skip_cleanup: true`. See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/#Uploading-Files.
No local changes to save

Deploying application
Deploying to ghpages-https
  Build cache: /home/travis/.cache/lektor/builds/d3a411e13041731555222b901cff4248
  Target: ghpages+https://pybee/pybee.github.io?cname=pybee.org
  Initialized empty Git repository in /home/travis/build/pybee/pybee.github.io/temp/.deploytemp9xhRDc/scratch/.git/
  Fetching origin
  fatal: repository 'https://github.com/pybee/pybee.github.io/' not found
  error: Could not fetch origin
  fatal: repository 'https://github.com/pybee/pybee.github.io/' not found
Done!
```

For a full log, [see here](https://travis-ci.org/pybee/pybee.github.io/builds/142337896).

I've checked the credentials in the Travis CI configuration for the repository; I'm as certain as I can be that they're correct. I've tried using the same configuration (exporting `LEKTOR_DEPLOY_USERNAME` and `LEKTOR_DEPLOY_PASSWORD` locally), and it works fine.

```
hammer:pybee.org rkm$ lektor deploy ghpages-https
Deploying to ghpages-https
  Build cache: /Users/rkm/Library/Caches/Lektor/builds/a269cf944d4302f15f78a1dfb1602486
  Target: ghpages+https://pybee/pybee.github.io?cname=pybee.org
  Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/rkm/projects/beeware/pybee.org/temp/.deploytempOh4p98/scratch/.git/
  Fetching origin
  From https://github.com/pybee/pybee.github.io
   * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
  On branch master
  Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
  nothing to commit, working directory clean
  Everything up-to-date
Done!
```

Any suggestions on the cause of this error?

Comment: Maybe try using a GitHub repo personal access token instead? As mentioned in the [Lektor docs](https://www.getlektor.com/docs/deployment/travisci/#access-credentials), as it seems like the authentication with GitHub is where it's failing.

Or maybe see if you can ramp up the amount of debug info for the deployment command.

Comment: The only difference I spot in the logs is that / at the end of Travis repo, is there any chance this is a typo in your configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this is a [bug in Lektor](https://github.com/lektor/lektor/pull/240).

If you use the following in your `<project>.lektorproject`:

```
[servers.ghpages-https]
target = ghpages+https://pybee/pybee.github.io?cname=pybee.org
```

and the following in your `.travis.yml`:

```
language: python
python: 2.7
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.cache/pip
    - $HOME/.cache/lektor/builds
install: "pip install git+https://github.com/singingwolfboy/lektor.git@fix-ghpages-https-deploy#egg=lektor"
script: "lektor build"
deploy:
  provider: script
  script: "lektor deploy ghpages-https"
  on:
    branch: lektor
```

(i.e., use the PR branch for deployment), builds will deploy as expected.

Comment: if the linked bug is resolved as the fix is merged now, please consider `accept`-ing your own answer.